# # character in URL and Scroll to top of the screen on page load

Tags: url

When I refresh a page, browsers retain the scroll position of the page if there is a `#` in the URL, How to over ride this behavior and scroll to the top of the screen without using JavaScript.

My URL is like `http://example.com/#`

**Update**
By default the URL is `http://example.com/` and the # character is added to the URL upon clicking some part of the page.

Comment: Can you add a `#top` element?

Comment: @KennyTM, by default the URL is `http://example.com/` and the # character is added to the URL upon clicking some part of the page.

Comment: My browser happily retains scroll position on a refresh without a hash character being present. But if you really want to avoid having that character in the URI, don't add it when the user clicks somewhere on the page! (Nothing a browser does by default will add it for a click on anything other than a link to a URL which includes the hash in the resolved URI!)

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a `<form action="#" ...>` somewhere, that's your culprit. Change it to `<form action="" ...>`.

Comment: href="#"? Oh dear. http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you have a # symbol either in form action or in link href.

Replace # with `javascript:;` in links.

Replace # with `index.php` or leave blank (`<form action=""...`) in forms.

Comment: Er... isn't mine almost the same?

Comment: No, it isn't. When the JS fails, "javascript:;" does not "work".